# Counter using only basic logic gates

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, counter

I'm trying to make a counter (0 > 9) using only basic logic gates , I used the master slave jk flip flop and it work fine except that I don't know how to make it reset to 0 again after 9.
[image: Master slave JK flip flop]

Comment: You will need to perform an analysis to work out the extra logic gates. (You need to add some.) Haven't you learned how, yet? (You can also just go look at the 7400 series decade counters (like the 7490?) and look at the logic they used. It's all there.)

Comment: Any questions? Or comments?

Answer (score 2):

You have master-slave JK FFs showing. To start, here's the transition table for that JK FF:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Transition} & \text{JK FF} \\\hline
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{c}
\text{start }\to\text{ end}\\\\
  0 \quad \to \quad 0\\
  1 \quad \to \quad 1\\
  0 \quad \to \quad 1\\
  1 \quad \to \quad 0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{c:c}
  J & K \\\\
  0&x\\
  x&0\\
  1&x\\
  x&1
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

So, here's your excitation table for 0..9 and then looping back to the start:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{State} & \text{Next State} & \text{Excitations}\\\hline\\
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\
  \vphantom{\left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{ccc}J & K & T & D\end{array} } \right.}\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  \\
  1&0&1&0\\
  1&0&1&1\\
  1&1&0&0\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  1&1&1&0\\
  1&1&1&1
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\
  \vphantom{\left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{ccc}J & K & T & D\end{array} } \right.}\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  \\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x\\
  x&x&x&x
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  Q_D & Q_C & Q_B & Q_A\\
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{c:c}J & K \\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    1&x\\
    x&0\\
    x&1\\
  \\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x
  \end{array} } \right. &
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{c:c}J & K \\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
    1&x\\
    x&0\\
    x&0\\
    x&0\\
    x&1\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
  \\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x
  \end{array} } \right. &
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{c:c}J & K\\
    0&x\\
    1&x\\
    x&0\\
    x&1\\
    0&x\\
    1&x\\
    x&0\\
    x&1\\
    0&x\\
    0&x\\
  \\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x
  \end{array} } \right. &
  \left.\overbrace{\begin{array}{c:c}J & K\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
    1&x\\
    x&1\\
  \\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x\\
    x&x
  \end{array} } \right.
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

These are the resulting K-Maps:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_D\text{ }J&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&0&0&0\\
\overline{Q_D}\: Q_C&0&0&1&0\\
\vphantom{Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}}Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&x&x&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_D\text{ }K&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&x&x&x&x\\
\overline{Q_D}\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
\vphantom{Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}}Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&0&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_C\text{ }J&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&0&1&0\\
\overline{Q_D}\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
\vphantom{Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}}Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&0&0&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_C\text{ }K&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&x&x&x&x\\
\overline{Q_D}\: Q_C&0&0&1&0\\
\vphantom{Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}}Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&x&x&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_B\text{ }J&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&0&1&x&x\\
\overline{Q_D}\: Q_C&0&1&x&x\\
\vphantom{Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}}Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&0&0&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_B\text{ }K&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&x&x&1&0\\
\overline{Q_D}\: Q_C&x&x&1&0\\
\vphantom{Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}}Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&x&x&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_A\text{ }J&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&1&x&x&1\\
\overline{Q_D}\: Q_C&1&x&x&1\\
\vphantom{Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}}Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&1&x&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Q_A\text{ }K&\overline{Q_B}\:\overline{Q_A}&\overline{Q_B}\: Q_A&Q_B \:Q_A&Q_B \:\overline{Q_A}\\
\hline
\overline{Q_D}\:\overline{Q_C}&x&1&1&x\\
\overline{Q_D}\: Q_C&x&1&1&x\\
\vphantom{Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}}Q_D\: Q_C&x&x&x&x\\
Q_D\:\overline{Q_C}&x&1&x&x
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

You should be able to readily generate the required J-K input logic from the above. (It only requires three 2-in AND gates to do it.)

For those who can view deleted edits, feel free to review the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If output = 1001 (9) then reset ., Then the LSB race from 1000 to 1001 to 0000 might be not noticeable, depending on delays. There may be ways to eliminate the race. (I forget, that was 50 yrs ago). But close enuf for now.

You may find they changed methods of counters as each family evolved from 74xx to 74LSxx to 74HCxx for this race condition. But it is still basically a divide by 5 and a  divide by 2 for a decade binary up counter.

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls90.pdf?ts=1640983125859&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FSN54LS90

The one thing to learn is how to do timing analysis with worst case cold for TTL and worst case slow when hot CMOS to avoid glitches.  Also, always buffer counter outputs if there is any chance of output transients generated by crosstalk or external reflections as this can upset the counter by feedback into inputs.

Back in the old days, we had to worry about mismatched vendor speeds for CMOS more than today so metastable or race conditions can occur when they are produced in greater volumes. I learned that in my 4th year of working for Earth Science, building a dozen portable geophone recorders with programmable timers for remote Seismic Recording synchronized to WWVB. It was designed by a Physics post-grad and the head of the  Physics and Geology Dept. came into the basement lab one day to find out why the dozen recorders didn't work. i had to explain the nuances of new CMOS in 1974 and Motorola was slower than Fairchild & Harris so the chips caused race conditions  in all the decade counters and I had  to rework the design to prevent these glitches. It worked and it was a "blast" seeing how sensitive these seismic geophones were. They picked up all the building HVAC vibrations and even me walking across the concrete floor or doing a knee bend 6 feet away. not to mention picking deer running a hundred meters away on a quiet highway between Thompson and Lynn Lake where the *blast* raised a lake from a raft full of Geogel dropped into an old mine shaft 200 miles south and we lost radio contact. So WWVB timing was necessary to synchronize recordings stopping Only moving vehicle on the highway full of miners going home. I stood with my white hard hat in the middle of the road as the driver stopped at the last second. he said what the'ell are you doing. i said, we're waiting for some blasting ahead. he said oh sorry! You should have seen the look on his face after 10 minutes of silence and all the galvometers were recording wiggles he couldn't see or hear. that was my summer job one year.