# Circuit using a D flip-flop and logic gates

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates, flipflop

How do I create a circuit with two inputs A and B and one output Q using only one D flip-flop and logic gates? The circuit should perform the following when the clock ticks:

```
AB = 00: retains current value of Q 
AB = 01: reset Q 
AB = 10: set Q 
AB = 11: invert Q
```

Comment: sell the D-flip flop and the gates you have and buy one JK-flip flop. If nobody wants to buy them build a 4-to-1 multiplexer which drives the D input just with the wanted next output.

Comment: I searched for "jk flip flop using d flip flop" on google: https://electrosome.com/d-flip-flop-conversion-techniques/

Comment: Tony, both responses above mine are useful to consider. There is a process (too quickly mentioned in the link by Miron) that can be followed: such as shown [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/623631/38098) or [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/602531/38098). If you should be able to independently produce an answer after reading and considering these ideas (or links), feel free to write up your own answer here and select it as the answer.

Comment: This has the feel of homework.  We don't answer homework until you have shown some effort.  We help, but we do not do the heavy lifting.  As in, waste your time (and ours) stating things you already know.  Post an attempt and we will critique it.